# Modern Fortran equivalent of an action statement shared by nested DO and GO TO

Tags: fortran

I have come across a nested `do` construct in an old code that I am using, and hoping to understand and modernize. It uses the same labelled action statement for termination of the `do` loops, as well as `go to` statement. Here is a simplified version, that illustrates the logic of the original code with some otherwise trivial operations:

```fortran
      subroutine original(lim)
      k=0
      do 10 i=1,4
        do 10 j=1,3
          k=k-2
          if (i>lim) go to 10
          k=k+i*j
 10   k=k+1
      write(*,*) k
      return
      end
```

After looking at other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63730527/3967096)
[on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25283121/3967096) (and external resources), this is my
best effort at rewriting the logic of the original code, without obsolescent features (and `go to`):

```fortran
subroutine modern(lim)
  integer, intent(in) :: lim
  integer :: i, j, k
  k=0
  outer: do i=1,4
    inner: do j=1,3
      k=k-2
      if (i>lim) then
        k=k+1
        cycle inner
      end if
      k=k+i*j
      k=k+1
    end do inner
  end do outer
  write(*,*) k
end subroutine modern
```

I tested the codes with the following program, including alternatives for triggering/not triggering the `go to` statement:

```fortran
  write(*, '(a)') 'original:'
  call original(2)
  call original(5)

  write(*, '(/,a)') 'modern:'
  call modern(2)
  call modern(5)
end
```

and it gives the same result for the original and my modern rewrite:

```
original:
 6
 48

modern:
 6
 48
```

The action statement complicated (for me) rewriting the `do` loops, one can not simply replace it
with two `end do` statements, and this is further complicated by the `go to`. My rewrite required
duplicating the action statement (at the end of the `inner` loop, and within the body of the `if`
statement). So my question is this:

- What is the canonical/recommended way for handling the shared labelled action statement?
- Is my `modern` subroutine a correct rewrite of the `original` one?
- Is it possible to rewrite the `original` code without duplicating the action statement (`k=k+1`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `original` subroutine is surely the type of code that the Fortran standard had in mind when deleting non-block DO constructs:

> The nonblock forms of the DO loop were confusing and hard to maintain. Shared termination and dual use of labeled action statements as do termination and branch targets were especially error-prone.

If we have a non-block DO with shared termination looking like

```
do 1
  do 1
1 <action>
```

then we can write the equivalent

```
do 2
  do 1
    <action>
  1 end do
2 end do
```

(where the labels here can be removed)

The action statement needs writing only once, and that's inside the innermost loop. Because it's a shared termination executing it once signals the end of the iteration of every DO construct sharing it.

If we branch to the action statement (with `go to`) from the innermost<sup>1</sup> construct, like

```
do 1
  do 1
    go to 1
1 <action>
```

we have the equivalent

```
do 3
  do 2
    go to 1
    1 <action>
  2 end do
3 end do
```

Our usual strategies for replacing `go to` branching then are available.

---

Let's apply this to the original loop (ignoring any logic changes for the same effect and using redundant statement labels)

```
do 10 i=1,4
  do 10 j=1,3
    k=k-2
    if (i>lim) go to 10
    k=k+i*j
10 k=k+1
```

We can write this as

```
do 30 i=1,4
  do 20 j=1,3
    k=k-2
    if (i>lim) go to 10
    k=k+i*j
    10 k=k+1
  20 end do
30 end do
```

Coming to the `go to`, we have (at least these) two simple approaches.

Negating the IF:

```
    if (i<=lim) k=k+i*j
    10 k=k+1
```

Using blocks:

```
    nogoto: block
      if (i>lim) exit nogoto
      k=k+i*j
    end block nogoto
    10 k=k+1
```

---

As you can see, the "duplication of the action statement" comes from the use of the `cycle` statement. In the rewritten loops you've had to duplicate the action statement because you don't reach the end of the loop where the action statement lives. The original loop doesn't have a `cycle` and cycling changes the behaviour of the loop (the shared termination isn't executed when cycling but is when gone-to).

---

<sup>1</sup> The situation is decidedly more complicated if the branch is not inside the innermost construct. For clarity of this answer I won't address that case here.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and stepwise explanation (as always!), much appreciated.  Regarding the target for obvious simplification, that is just a consequence of my poor choice of  `k=k-1` as operation in the example (combined with `k=k+1` in the action statement). Maye I should edit the question and change `k=k-1` into `k=k*2`...

Comment: That's a good point: I managed to ignore the fact that the no-op is actually swallowing the termination action statement. Modifying the question so that the statement is doing something useful would help.

Comment: I edited the code examples in the question so that the conditionally performed operation in the inner loop, and the action statement are more distinct.

Comment: Nice explanation.  I believe your code is wrong for the `do 3` example as there is no statement with a `3` label.  Likely need a `3 end do`.

Comment: Thanks, @steve, quite so.